# Custom Dialog window gets disabled when in a method needing a return value

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019

The page will only show when the Task.Delay() is used!

Note: Updated to give more information on my code/calls, also I have found out that if the custom dialog window method gets called anywhere where there is a return method, then the dialog window is disabled (at least nothing works on the dialog), if i place the same call within a void method I do not need the await Task.Delay and everything is responsive, such as the activity indicator is spinning and so on...

here the page gets initialized...

```cs
    public void InitLoadingPage(ContentPage loadingPage = null)
    {
        // check if the page parameter is available
        if (loadingPage != null)
        {
            // build the loading page with native base
            loadingPage.Parent = Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.MainPage;
            loadingPage.Layout(new Rectangle(0, 0,
            Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.MainPage.Width,
            Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.MainPage.Height));
            var renderer = loadingPage.GetOrCreateRenderer();
            _nativeView = renderer.View;
            _dialog = new Dialog(CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity);

            _dialog.RequestWindowFeature((int)WindowFeatures.NoTitle);

            _dialog.SetCancelable(true);

            _dialog.SetContentView(_nativeView);

            Window window = _dialog.Window;

            window.SetLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent);

            window.ClearFlags(WindowManagerFlags.DimBehind);

            window.SetBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent));
            _isInitialized = true;
        }
    }
```

Here is the method to show the page..

```cs
    public void ShowLoadingPage()
    {
        // check if the user has set the page or not
        if (!_isInitialized)
            InitLoadingPage(new LoadingPageDefault()); // set the default page

        // showing the native loading page
        _dialog.Show();
    }
```

And it gets called like so...

```cs
   DependencyService.Get<ILodingPageService>().InitLoadingPage(new NetWorkScanPage());
   DependencyService.Get<ILodingPageService>().ShowLoadingPage();
   while (BaseObject.IsBusy)
   {
      await Task.Delay(1000).ConfigureAwait(true);
   }
   BaseObject.IsBusy = true;
```

My question is...Is there a way of showing the window without having to use the await Task.Delay(1000)?

Comment: What do you mean with Dialog/Window? Are you talking about the "native" DisplayAlert?

Comment: Hi Mihail, No it's not a DisplayAlert window, I am using a service to initialize some custom popup pages.`DependencyService.Get<ILodingPageService>().InitLoadingPage(new AddConnectionDetails(BaseControl.Shares));
                            ` it gets it's properties set as a dialog page and then I call .. `DependencyService.Get<ILodingPageService>().ShowLoadingPage();`

Comment: This all works fine, when the `ShowLoadingPage();` is called it needs `await Task.Delay(1000).ConfigureAwait(true);` to actually show the dialog. The page is then displayed, this I can place in a `while()` loop and wait for user input.

Comment: Maybe I have made my question to simple :-(

Comment: Yes, you have. Please update your question with more details. When you are using your own custom implementation of the dialog, a lot can happen in-between. Also, it is not a good practice to call multiple DependecyService.Get<ILoadingPageSerivce>. Instead of this, simply store the service in a readonly ILoadingPageService field.

Comment: Sorry for the simplicity then, I made it simple only because I don't have problems with the service or the way it opens and closes the custom (shall we say popups) I just needed to do something when the popup had finished it's loading proccess.

Comment: @Mark According to your description, you have no problem, but you just want to display custom dialog without using Task.Delay()?

Comment: @Cherry, thank you for your reply, there was  small issue that the window would not show if the call was placed within a method that needed a return value, I then found out that I needed to wrap the method that had the return value  within an awaitable Task when returning a value. If I just placed the ShowLoadingPage within a public void, then it would show the page immediately. I will place this post as answered now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by placing the the method that I was calling within an awaitable Task, I know this is due to the fact that I am still learning how to code correctly, but I will post my solution anyway, incase someone like me has the same problem :-)

```
    public async Task<bool> SomeMethod()
    {
        DependencyService.Get<ILodingPageService>().InitLoadingPage(new YourLoadingPage());
        DependencyService.Get<ILodingPageService>().ShowLoadingPage();
        var SomeValue = false;
        if (await WhileIsBusy())
        {
            // Do stuff...
            SomeValue = true; // Some other Method that returns a value
        }
        return SomeValue;
    }
    public static async Task<bool> WhileIsBusy(int frequency = 25, int timeout = -1)
    {
        bool IsBusy = true; // This can be a property in your BaseViewModel
        bool Completed = false;
        var waitTask = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            while (IsBusy)
            {
                await Task.Delay(frequency);
                Completed = SomeMethodToReturn();
                IsBusy = false;
            }
        });
        if (waitTask != await Task.WhenAny(waitTask, Task.Delay(timeout)))
        {
            throw new TimeoutException();
        }
        return Completed;
    }
```

This will keep the LoadingPage active while waiting for the return value, when all is finished you can then call ...

```
DependencyService.Get<ILodingPageService>().HideLoadingPage();
```

I hope this helps someone like me who is still trying to learn.